# Give an example of a series

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Give an example of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$, $a_n>0$, such, that $\sum a_n<\infty$, but $\sum a_n\log n=\infty$

I can use only: limit comparison, Raabe, Cauchy's condensation, ratio and root tests, because I don't know integrals and differentials.
I have no idea how to solve it.

Comment: This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Answer (score 2):

Let $$a_n=\frac{1}{n\,(\log n)^2}$$ $\{a_n\}$ is summable; use the integral test and substitute $u=\log x$. But $\{a_n\log n\}$ is not; again use the integral test with the same substitution.

---

As JessicaK notes, Cauchy's condensation works too: $$2^na_{2^n}=2^n\frac{1}{2^n(\log 2^n)^\varepsilon}=\frac{1}{n^\varepsilon(\log 2)^\varepsilon}$$
where $\varepsilon$ is either $1$ or $2$. Cauchy's condensation is conceptually almost the same as an integral test with the substitution $u=\log_2(x)$.

---

We can directly see that $\left\{\frac{1}{n\log n}\right\}$ is not summable (by essentially re-proving Cauchy's condensation):
$$
\begin{aligned}\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n\log n}&=(\log 2)\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n\log_2 n}\\
&=\log2\left(\frac{1}{2\log_22}+\frac{1}{3\log_23}+\frac{1}{4\log_24}+\frac{1}{5\log_25}+\cdots+\frac{1}{8\log_28}+\cdots\right)\\
&>\log2\left(\frac{1}{2\log_22}+\overbrace{\frac{1}{4\log_24}+\frac{1}{4\log_24}}+\overbrace{\frac{1}{8\log_28}+\cdots+\frac{1}{8\log_28}}+\cdots\right)\\
&=\log2\left(\frac{1}{2\cdot1}+\frac{2}{4\cdot2}+\frac{4}{8\cdot3}+\cdots\right)\\
&=\frac{\log2}{2}\left(\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots\right)\\
\end{aligned}$$

Something similar (using $<$ instead of $>$) can show that $\left\{\frac{1}{n\,(\log n)^2}\right\}$ is summable through comparison with $\left\{\frac{1}{n^2}\right\}$.

Comment: Do you know some way without integrals?

Comment: You can use the Cauchy condensation test on the above $a_{n}$.